# Jupyter Notebookが起動できない問題

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Anaconda3をインストールしました。OSはWindows10です。

Anaconda Promptを開き、`jupyter notebook` と打ち込んでみました。

以下のエラーが発生して、jupyter notebookを起動できません。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 51, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。
```

Anaconda3は `C:\Users\[ユーザー名]` の中にインストールしてあります。
解決策をご存じの方がいれば、教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: Anaconda Navigatorを起動し、Anaconda NavigatorのメニューからJupyter Notebookは起動できますか？

Comment: エラーメッセージは略さないで全て記述してください。重要な情報が抜け落ちてしまうかもしれません。

Comment: 今回のエラーメッセージの場合、どの DLL あるいはモジュールにおいてエラーが発生したかが特に重要そうです。これらの情報を [edit] して追記していただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: すいません、エラーメッセージを追記しました。

Comment: 後、Anaconda Navigatorも起動できていないです。。

Comment: エラーメッセージを見る限りは Anaconda3 のインストール先は `C:\Users\ユーザー名` ではなくて `C:\ProgramData` になっているようですが、これは想定通りでしょうか？　ユーザー名を隠すために手で修正した、とかなら分かるのですが……。

Comment: 関連しそうな英語版 Stack Overflow での質問です: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63979186/5989200

Comment: 上記リンク先の対応と再インストールで解決しました。ありがとうございます。